# Is it safe to call FirebaseAnalytics's setUserProperty() each time on app launch?

Tags: android, firebase-analytics

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics#setUserProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) for FirebaseAnalytics mentions that the value "persists throughout the app lifecycle and across sessions". When we call `setUserProperty()`, is the value stored locally or is it associated with the Firebase user via a n/w call?

Our use case may need that we call the above method on each app launch. If the value is stored locally, then I guess we can call that method on app launches safely. If however, a n/w call is involved, we need to keep track if the value is set (via SharedPreferences maybe) and set the value only if not yet set to save an extraneous n/w call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is fairly common to set user properties whenever the app starts. Doing so is not a known cause of problems.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.